# How to set up OSX dev machines to install clean at a specific time

Tags: macos, puppet, devops, boxen

Does anyone know an easy way to set up OSX dev machines to install xcode and set up a clean dev environment every morning at 5am?

I was looking at using something like boxen, but the problem I was facing is they all need Xcode installed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually automate a lot of the pre-requites for Boxen with scripts, such as automating the Xcode installation step with a script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get and install Xcode CLI tools
OSX_VERS=$(sw_vers -productVersion | awk -F "." '{print $2}')

# on 10.9+, we can leverage SUS to get the latest CLI tools
if [ "$OSX_VERS" -ge 9 ]; then
    # create the placeholder file that's checked by CLI updates' .dist code
    # in Apple's SUS catalog
    touch /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
    # find the CLI Tools update
    PROD=$(softwareupdate -l | grep "\*.*Command Line" | head -n 1 | awk -F"*" '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/^ *//' | tr -d '\n')
    # install it
    softwareupdate -i "$PROD" -v

# on 10.7/10.8, we instead download from public download URLs, which can be found in
# the dvtdownloadableindex:
# https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/simulators/index-3905972D-B609-49CE-8D06-51ADC78E07BC.dvtdownloadableindex
else
    [ "$OSX_VERS" -eq 7 ] && DMGURL=http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/command_line_tools_for_xcode_os_x_lion_april_2013.dmg
    [ "$OSX_VERS" -eq 8 ] && DMGURL=http://devimages.apple.com/downloads/xcode/command_line_tools_for_osx_mountain_lion_april_2014.dmg

    TOOLS=clitools.dmg
    curl "$DMGURL" -o "$TOOLS"
    TMPMOUNT=`/usr/bin/mktemp -d /tmp/clitools.XXXX`
    hdiutil attach "$TOOLS" -mountpoint "$TMPMOUNT"
    installer -pkg "$(find $TMPMOUNT -name '*.mpkg')" -target /
    hdiutil detach "$TMPMOUNT"
    rm -rf "$TMPMOUNT"
    rm "$TOOLS"
    exit
fi
```